# What does the word "topically" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The drugs can be administered orally, or **topically**.

Comment: Try [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topical?q=topical),2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topical_medication) that the drug can be applied to a body surface (e.g. skin).

> A topical medication is a medication that is applied to body surfaces such as the skin or mucous membranes to treat ailments via a large range of classes including but not limited to creams, foams, gels, lotions and ointments.

Comment: Nicotine and testosterone can both be applied directly to the skin without being topical.

Answer (score 0):

A drug administered **topically** is applied directly to the part of the body that it is intended to treat.  It is contrasted with systemic administration where the drug works by being mixed into fluids that circulate in the body. See [Topical Medication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topical_medication) at Wikipedia.